# How do I make my background colour start off as light blue gradually become dark blue?

Tags: javascript, css

I would really like to know how to create this effect in Javascript where the background gradient changes radially. How do they do this?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want JavaScript solution? You can achieve this with only CSS

Comment: Go to [colorzillas' gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) and under **Preview** change orientation to **radial**

Comment: I didn't know @LucaDetomi, awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need javascript in this work, just use CSS [`radial-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient)

```css
#grad {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #474747, #999); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="grad"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) you can generate the following, that is compatible with almost all browsers:

```
.gradient-class
{
  background: #7db9e8; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7db9e8 0%, #1e5799 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#7db9e8), color-stop(100%,#1e5799)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #7db9e8 0%,#1e5799 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7db9e8', endColorstr='#1e5799',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be helpful

```
<div class="abc">
</div>

.abc{
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 display:inline-block;
background: rgba(73,155,234,1);
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(73,155,234,1) 32%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 60%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(73,155,234,1)), color-stop(32%, rgba(73,155,234,1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(32,124,229,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(32,124,229,1)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(73,155,234,1) 32%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 60%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(73,155,234,1) 32%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 60%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(73,155,234,1) 32%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 60%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(73,155,234,1) 32%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 60%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#499bea', endColorstr='#207ce5', GradientType=1 );
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vhxa2xbb/)